# Updating Partial Views From Controller in .Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to update the Partial Views from Controller means one Partial View is on the page but when I want get another partial containing modified data from controller but that was appending instead of being replaced with the existing div  so this solved as explained in the answer but my question was not clear so modified it.

Comment: return PartialView("_Partialview ", Model);                                                                        then i want to add for the second need to update the same partial view not to append new

Comment: you can use jquery or ajax to do it

Comment: You must post your code properly in order us to understand your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Jquery Ajax for this
Try something like this..

```
$('#Yourbutton').on('click', function(){
    $('#yourdiv').empty();
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("YOUR Action", "YOUR Controller")',
        dataType: 'html',
        cache: false,
        async: true,
        data : {Yourparam1:value ,YourParam2:value }
        success: function(result){
            $('#yourdiv').append(result);
        } 
    });
});
```

Here I assume that there is a `div` in your page to hold partial view data

Comment: yes but what about the parameters ?

Comment: giving me error near success: function(result) for Expected ;

Comment: thanks  tarzanbappa